# Play pawn-only chess vs a friend

Tags: online-chess, teaching

I am teaching a youngster how to play chess, remotely.  I've seen suggestions to start with [pawn-only chess](https://www.chessvariants.com/diffsetup.dir/pawnsonly.html), where we start with the initial setup for all 16 pawns, but no other pieces on the board.  I would play to play an online live game vs my friend.  Is it possible to do that on lichess?

I've tried going to the board editor, deleting all pieces other than the pawns, and using the 'From Position' variant, but that doesn't work: I can't create a game.

Comment: There's more on this world than Lichess

Comment: @David, Sure!  Got another site or method you'd recommend for playing remotely, online?

Answer (score 6):

The 'From Position' variant seems to require that both sides have a king.  So, keep the kings on the board.  In particular, create a new game with a friend, select Variant: From Position, and paste '4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/4K3 w - - 0 1' into the field for the FEN text.

```
4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/4K3 w - - 0 1
```